# R function for selecting an x amount of observations per hour\day that are evenly separated

Tags: r, time, subset

I am trying to create a function that selects a defined amount of observations per a defined time frame.

I have managed to create a function that subsets for one observation per hour:

```
#create example df 
timestamp <- seq(ISOdate(2022,05,20), ISOdate(2022,05,22), "min")
Animal_ID <- c(rep("Avi",length(timestamp)), rep("David",length(timestamp)))
timestamp <-as.character(c(timestamp,timestamp))
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(Animal_ID,timestamp))

#function
OnePerHour <- function(df){
  dataOnePerHour <- df %>% 
    group_by(Animal_ID, hour(timestamp), as.Date(timestamp))%>%
    filter(row_number(Animal_ID) == 1)
  return(dataOnePerHour)
}
```

However, I am not able to work my head around expanding so I would be able to select more obs/hour that are evenly distributed.

In this example, there is an observation every minute but in the "real dataset" there might be only three or four observations/hr that is 15 mins apart for one animal and an observation every second for another. So, lets say that I am looking for 3 obs\hr, and observation freq is 1/min so 1, 21, 41 is exactly what I am looking for.  If there are only three (15 mins apart) I would like to include all of the observations.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Idan

Comment: Can you give some examples of what you are expecting as a result? If you want 2 obs/hour, do you want minutes 1 & 31? If 3, then 1, 21, 41? Will the time frame always be an hour? Will the data always have the same frequency of observations for each `Animal_ID`?

Comment: Thanks, Ihs. The observation freq is not always the same Animal_ID. In my example, there is an observation every minute but in the "real dataset" there might be only three or four observations that are 15 mins apart for one animal and an observation every second for another. So, lets say that I am looking for 3 obs\hr, and observation freq is 1/min so 1, 21, 41 is exactly what I am looking for.  If there are only three (15 mins apart) I would like to include all of observations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that creates `times_per_hour` equally spaced intervals within every hour for every `Animal_ID`, and then chooses the first observation within that interval. If there aren't any observations within that interval, however, no observation will be chosen. So if you want 3 per hour and you have observations at 12:01, 12:02, and 12:03, you're only going to get the first one, because there were no observations between 12:20-12:40 or 12:40-1:00.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

#create example df 
timestamp <- seq(ISOdate(2022,05,20), ISOdate(2022,05,22), "min")
Animal_ID <- c(rep("Avi",length(timestamp)), rep("David",length(timestamp)))
timestamp <-as.character(c(timestamp,timestamp))
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(Animal_ID,timestamp))

get_observations <- function(df, times_per_hour, min_date_time, max_date_time) {
  
  # madke dataframe with all possible minutes between min and max times
  timespan <- expand_grid(Animal_ID = unique(df$Animal_ID),
                          # replace with min and max datetimes of the data
                          timestamp = seq(min_date_time, max_date_time, "min"))
  
  ideal_times <- timespan %>% 
    group_by(Animal_ID, hour = hour(timestamp), date = as.Date(timestamp)) %>% 
    # select the beginning of the interval from which you want an observation
    slice(seq(1, n(), by = 60/times_per_hour)) %>% 
    mutate(time_interval = interval(timestamp, 
                                    lead(timestamp, default = max_date_time))) %>% 
    select(-timestamp)
  
  df %>% 
    mutate(hour = hour(timestamp), date = as.Date(timestamp)) %>% 
    # join so every time interval is matched with all the obs in that hour
    right_join(ideal_times, by = c("Animal_ID", "hour", "date")) %>% 
    # then remove all the obs that aren't in the exact interval
    filter(as_datetime(timestamp) %within% time_interval) %>% 
    group_by(Animal_ID, time_interval) %>% 
    # then take the first observation
    slice(1) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    select(-time_interval)

}

# choose 10% so that observations are not equally spaced
sample_df <- slice_sample(df, prop = .1)
get_observations(sample_df, times_per_hour = 3, 
                 min_date_time = ISOdate(2022,05,20), max_date_time = ISOdate(2022,05,22))

#> # A tibble: 259 × 4
#>    Animal_ID timestamp            hour date      
#>    <chr>     <chr>               <int> <date>    
#>  1 Avi       2022-05-20 12:00:00    12 2022-05-20
#>  2 Avi       2022-05-20 12:32:00    12 2022-05-20
#>  3 Avi       2022-05-20 12:48:00    12 2022-05-20
#>  4 Avi       2022-05-20 13:15:00    13 2022-05-20
#>  5 Avi       2022-05-20 13:35:00    13 2022-05-20
#>  6 Avi       2022-05-20 13:52:00    13 2022-05-20
#>  7 Avi       2022-05-20 14:17:00    14 2022-05-20
#>  8 Avi       2022-05-20 14:28:00    14 2022-05-20
#>  9 Avi       2022-05-20 14:48:00    14 2022-05-20
#> 10 Avi       2022-05-20 15:16:00    15 2022-05-20
#> # … with 249 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, I might do something like this. Maybe a bit long, I will add in the date, hour, minute, and calculate the time difference from previous time point per animal ID first.

Then calculate the number of observation in an hour, and create a filter logical column based on your description.

```
  df <- df %>% 
  mutate(dt = as.Date(timestamp),
         hr = hour(timestamp),
         m = minute(timestamp)) %>% 
  group_by(Animal_ID) %>% 
  mutate(time_diff = m-lag(m)) 

df <- df %>% 
  group_by(Animal_ID,
           dt,
           hr) %>% 
  mutate(num_in_hour = n(),
         filterlogic = (num_in_hour == 60 & m %in% c(1,21,41))|(num_in_hour %in% c(3,4)&time_diff==15)
  ) %>% 
  filter(filterlogic == TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin for your answer but for whatever reason, the code does not work and I am looking for something more general. for example, another scenario I may need to deal with is the need to extract four evenly distributed observations from un hour that has twelve (one every five minutes).

Comment: Sorry, changed some codes and didn't test it, it should work now, but I guess that's not general enough. If you can specify your requirement a bit more, or show some real data, maybe we can help you more